# Filter a field containing a value

Tags: sql-server

I'm starting to learn SQL. Im using SQL Server Management Studio to write my queries in. I unserstand that I can filter a field contaning a given value (for example : product A, product A (cost), product B, product B (cost)) so in this instance I can filter out values containing "(cost)". I've arrived at the following query but its failing. Can you tell me why.

```
SELECT     billing_code, billing_code_desc
FROM         dbo.jm_billing_code
WHERE     (NOT (billing_code_desc = N'CONTAIN [(cost)]'))
ORDER BY billing_code
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187787.aspx

Answer (score 4):

`N'CONTAIN [(cost)]'` is a string literal, you can't place functions like `contain` in there.

Try this instead:

```
where billing_code_desc not like '%(cost)%'
```

Answer (score 3):

To exclude results that have cost:

```
 SELECT     billing_code, billing_code_desc
    FROM         dbo.jm_billing_code
    WHERE     billing_code_desc NOT LIKE '%(cost)%'
    ORDER BY billing_code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE NOT(CONTAINS(billing_code_desc, N'cost'))
```

Should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to filter for rows that have `(cost)` in `billing_code_desc` then you should do

```
AND CONTAINS(billing_code_desc, '(cost)')
```

See [contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258227%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: OP wants to filter OUT (cost)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT billing_code, billing_code_desc FROM dbo.jm_billing_Code 
WHERE billing_code_desc NOT LIKE '%(Cost)%' 
ORDER BY billing_code
```